# Internal Set Theory: $n$ is standard $\implies\;n+1$ is standard

Tags: logic, nonstandard-analysis

I'm reading a bit about Nelson's version of nonstandard analysis and in the notes it is said that [$n$ is standard]$\implies$[$n+1$ is standard]. Right after that it is mentioned that an inductive proof is impossible (using the fact $0$ is standard as the base) because it would be based on external sets. I have two questions about this:

1. My proof attempt: We're given a standard $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the internal formula $A(x)$ defined by $[x=n+1]$ (emphasizing dependence on $x$ with $n$ being a parameter). By a version of the transfer principle $\forall^{\text{st}}n[\exists^{\text{st}}xA(x)\iff \exists xA(x)]$, $x=n+1$ can be chosen standard, and by the uniqueness of $n+1$ it necessarily is standard. Is this correct?
2. Since any object that can be uniquely described in internal mathematics is standard, why exactly is it untrue that every natural is standard? After all, no matter what $n\in\mathbb{N}$ i'm given, I can uniquely describe it using the typical $\left\{ \emptyset,\left\{ \emptyset \right\},\dots \right\}$..  What exactly is wrong about this approach of dealing with each natural number separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument that $n+1$ is standard if $n$ is seems correct; I would suggest a different approach: show that evaluating a standard function at a standard value produces a standard value. Then this problem would follow by using $f(x) = x+1$.

For your second question, are you *sure* every natural number can be written as $\{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing \}, \ldots \}$?

You're making a level slip here: every natural number within an IST-universe can indeed be expressed by an string of symbols $\{\},\varnothing$ one can construct within the IST-universe. But that does not imply it can be expressed by an *external* string of the same symbols.

(in fact, depending precisely on your choice foundations, you might even have *standard* natural numbers that can't be expressed by external strings)

Comment: What does that show about the set-theoretic formula?

Comment: This is a little confusing because you are not using "external" in the same sense OP used it. What you are referring to apparently is the construction of a model for Nelson's IST starting with the intended model of ZFC.

Comment: @user: I intend "external" to mean "of the formal logic in which I've written the axioms of IST" and anything else on the same level (e.g. the associated notion of natural number)

Comment: @user: I think it was "internal" I was using differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Two questions: 1) Doesn't the usual recursive set-theoretic definition of $\mathbb{N}$ indeed enable us to write every natural number in that way? 2) What does internal/external string mean?

Comment: @Exterior: You're writing things -- e.g. the axioms of IST -- in a formal language. I am using "external" to refer to things in that formal language. Using IST, you can define a notion of formal language. I had been using "internal" to refer to that notion. You can prove the existence of an injection from the "set of natural numbers" to "the set of strings". But it's too much to expect for every element of "the set of strings" to be given by an external string. (in fact, I don't think you *can* ask that syntactically: such a question only makes sense given a model)

Comment: I don't understand most of your comment, so it looks like i'll have to read some more about logic and IST and retry later :D 
Could you elaborate on the problem of writing natural numbers in the mentioned way in a more elementary way? Thanks again!

Comment: @Exterior: It's tricky. Have you seen Skolem's paradox? It's essentially the same problem -- it conflates two different uses of the word 'countable': one used by the set theory you used to develop formal logic, and one used by the theory of ZFC that you are studying via formal logic -- but it might be easier to find literature on it.

Comment: I haven't seen it but i'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The formula $x=n+1$ is internal but the statement $[n \text{ standard}] \implies [n+1 \text{ standard}]$ is not. You haven't provided a proof that does not involve external entities.

Comment: The statement we're trying to prove involves external entities, so it's unavoidable that external entities will be involved.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thanks for your comment. I am not sure how to respond to the OP's remark about the set-theoretic construction. Do you want to try?